# dc.js Remove clicked slice in PIE chart instead of grey out?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to remove the selected slice from the PIE chart instead of grey out. For example [DC page](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) either "Days by Gain/Loss" or "Quarters" PIE chart if I click on the slice (say Q4) I want to remove that entry from display (including slice + legend, if I want to restore I can use controls to reset it).

How to achieve that behaviour?

I have tried the following in the click handler:

```
let filter = chart.keyAccessor()(d);
            if (d3.event['shiftKey']) {
                if ('Others' === filter) {
                    chart['_invokeFilteredListener'](Array.isArray(filter)? filter : [filter], 'error');
                } else {
                    chart['__inclusive'] = true;
                    chart['replaceFilter'](filter);
                    //if (multivalued) {
                    dc.redrawAll(); //why renderAll()?
                    //}
                }
            } else {
                dc.events.trigger(() => {
                    chart.filter(filter);
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });
            }
```

`filterHandler`:

```
.filterHandler((dim: Crossfilter2.Dimension<any, any>, filters: string[]) => {
                dim.filter(null);
                const data = this._chart.data();
                const filterObject = {};
                for (let f of filters) {
                    if ('Others' === f) {
                        let others: any[] = data[data.length - 1].others;
                        if (Array.isArray(others)) {
                            for (let o of others) {
                                filterObject[o] = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            dim.group().all().forEach(g => {
                                let p = filters.indexOf(g.key);
                                if (p < 0) {
                                    filterObject[g.key] = p;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        filterObject[f] = true;
                    }
                }
                dim.filterFunction(d => {
                    return filterObject[Array.isArray(d)? d[0] : d] !== void 0;
                });
                return filters;
            });
```

Comment: Do you want to filter out the pie slice when it is removed, so that no other chart displays that data either? Seems to me the easier route might be to use a different dimension from the one the chart's group is defined on, so that the chart *does* affect itself.

Comment: @Gordon, That is the only way? The problem to create the dimension is the performance. The data exploration platform I'm working can have 12 charts and datagrid (custom). If we have to take the dimension route it will be huge performance issues pops up. We usually have data anywhere between 2-millions to 5 millions.

Comment: I expect you're already having performance problems with that many rows. I never recommend going above 500K rows. But sure, there's always another way. My question stands: do you want to filter the data when the pie slice is hidden?

Comment: Yes, I want to filter the data when pie slice is hidden. 
- Regarding performance, yes we have challenges but we have implemented custom crossfilter (same API) but works on indexed data, for example ```[{name: 1, age: 20}, {name: 2, age: 40}, {name: 3, age: 50}, {name: 5, age: 60}]``` we will convert this into indexed object array ```{name: [1,L2,5], age: [20, 40,S10_L2]}``` and we aggregate the data and expand only if grid is present, so the overall performance is not bad :). Will open source when its stable (we also have to the java code).

Comment: Awesome! I'd love to see that. I came up with one possible solution below. Sort of hacky, it just reverses each one of the assumptions that dc.js makes. As you can see, the idea is contrary to dc.js and crossfilter in a lot of ways - still a great idea though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do it, but the first thing I thought was, of, "sounds like a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups)" that behaves like an ordinary group but it does observe its own dimension's filters:

```
function filter_self_group(chart, group) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            var filters = chart.filters();
            return group.all().filter(kv => !filters.includes(kv.key));
        }
    };
}
yearRingChart
    .group(filter_self_group(yearRingChart, spendPerYear))
```

Just grab the filters from the chart and make sure those bins are excluded. This doesn't deal with Others but that's simple enough to add.

Next, we want to filter *out* values instead of filtering them *in* like dc.js normally does. We can do this by modifying the default filter handler. I think this is similar to what you're doing above, but simpler:

```
function negate_filters(dimension, filters) {
    if (filters.length === 0)
        dimension.filter(null);
    else
        dimension.filterFunction(function(d) {
            return !filters.includes(d);
        })
    return filters;
}
```

Also, I thought it would be nice if, when you filter out the last slice, that resets the filter:

```
function all_is_nothing(N, filterHandler) {
    return function(dimension, filters) {
        console.log(filters.length, N)
        if(filters.length === N)
            filters = [];
        return filterHandler(dimension, filters);
    }
}
```

Tying those together:

```
yearRingChart
    .filterHandler(all_is_nothing(spendPerYear.all().length, negate_filters));
```

Finally, the "deselected grey" isn't useful to us, and I couldn't figure out how to disable the effects of the CSS rule, so let's just remove the class from the slices after the chart draws, but before it's shown:

```
yearRingChart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('g.deselected').classed('deselected', false);
});
```

I'm sure there are many other ways to do this, and maybe there are cleaner ways. This is what came to mind. I'd be happy to add support for Others but I wanted to present the basic idea first.

[Here is an example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/f3ntqxw8/24/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the best part of your answer is not just throw some code but you explains which is more important in the learning ```dcjs```. I heartfelt thanks.